# Values in column to reverse order

Tags: sas

i need help in finding how to convert datavalues in a column to reverse order into new column or same column.I mean first datavalue in column should be the last value in column and vice versa.

example:
name   age
karl   40
lowry  56
jim    29
robert 34
samuel 60
harry  47

the output i need should look like this.

name   age
harry   47
samuel  60
robert  34
jim     29
lowry   56
karl    40
i need reverse order of the datavalues on variables age and name or only on one variable.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far and explain what it is or is not doing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable of the observation number:

```
data temp;
    set have;
    ObsNum = _n_;
run;
```

Then use that variable to sort the dataset:

```
proc sort data=temp out=want (drop=ObsNum);
    by descending ObsNum;
run;
```

Comment: This works for both the variables. i also need to reverse any one variable i.e age.